# NSIS copy folder to a network Drive and ftp site

Tags: ftp, nsis, network-drive

Hi I would like to copy all the files from a folder on my local machine to a network drive. 
I tried using CopyFiles "....\Source*.*" "\abc\Destination" But its not working.....
I also tried File /r "....\Source*.*" "\abc\Destination".
Please let me know where am i going wrong. Also please let me know how to copy the folder on the ftp site

Comment: @Bananeweizen: he has only 1 other out of 3 with acceptable answer. One has no answer and the last is the current one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copyfiles uses [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) internally and should work as long as you follow that api's restrictions, especially the part about full paths: "**It cannot be overstated that your paths should always be full paths**" and "**Standard MS-DOS wildcard characters, such as "*", are permitted only in the file-name position. Using a wildcard character elsewhere in the string will lead to unpredictable results**"